# SPLink.UrlParameter

Tags: spweb

Is there a way to assign value to Microsoft.SharePoint.SPLink.UrlParameter. From MSDN, I see that this is parameter is read only, but was wondering is there any setter function that would have access to this variable.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the instead the SPFieldUrlValue  as below, where the newLink["URL"] is the SPListItem reference of your List item:

```
SPFieldUrlValue value = new SPFieldUrlValue();

value.Description = "test";

value.Url = "www.microsoft.com/sharepoint";

newLink["URL"] = value;

newLink.Update();
```